# Moq setup does not match parameter because it is a subtype?

Tags: types, parameters, mocking, moq, expectations

I'm trying to use `Setup` on a Moq like I've done many times to return a value, but I can't seem to understand why the parameter matching fails in this case.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var myParameter = new SomeParameter();
myMock.Setup(x => x.SomeFunction(myParameter)).Returns(myResult);
```

Where `SomeParameter : IParameter` and the function is defined as `SomeFunction(IParameter parameter)`.

If I change the first line to:

```
IParameter myParameter = new SomeParameter();
```

or indeed, cast it:

```
myMock.Setup(x => x.SomeFunction((IParameter)myParameter))).Returns(myResult);
```

It works fine.

Is this normal behavior, or a bug? Can I configure Moq to not check the compile-time type of whatever parameter I'm passing in?

Using Moq 4.5.30, slightly older version.

Comment: Wont be able to be sure based on the limited example provided. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just tested with version 4.7.99 and works as expected.

Comment: @Nkosi I would love to upgrade but we're stuck on Castle.Core 3.3... Moq requires Castle.Core >= 4.0 in versions after 4.5.30. I'm completely baffled anyway. I just can't imagine all my parameters were always the same compile-time type when doing setups.

Comment: Then based on that restriction, you are left with what you have already discovered works. That was something that was fixed in subsequent updates to the lib.

Comment: I suggest checking the change log to find out specifically when it was fixed https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @Nkosi I already glanced over it, no entry in it seems to indicate a fix to this particular bug, but there are entries related to parameter matching so I don't doubt it's fixed.

Comment: @MarioDS: Your repro code isn't complete so it's hard to tell what's going wrong, but I tried to reconstruct [something close to your code](https://pastebin.com/VxEcETy8) and it worked just fine even with Moq 4.5.30... parameter type polymorphism should work just fine. Please provide minimally complete and verifiable code like Nkosi suggested, then we might be able to help.